# Populate Javascript array with excel data

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel

Ok, I'm new to `javascript` (learning quickly though).  I've been able to cobble together some code which does a couple of things.

1. Opens/reads an excel file (local now but will be on server).  Get
   cell `A1` (will always be a `#`) - variable repCount.
2. Writes cells `A2-A33` to a table in html (hard coded start and stop)

Now what I would it to do is

1. take the repCount variable as the ending row in the writing part - dynamic stop point
2. write it to an array that I can manipulate (should be globally available).

Here's my code so far:

```
 <script language="javascript" >
 // Open the spreadsheet and get the count of reps
 function GetData(cell,row)
     {
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("SOMEFILE.xlsx");
    var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
    var repCount = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
    document.getElementById('div1').innerText = repCount; 
    }

 //   open spreadsheet and populate table with representatives
     var excelApp=null, excelFile=null, excelSheet=null;
     var filename = "SOMEFILE.xlsx";

 function initExcel(filename)
      {
      excelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      excelFile = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
      excelSheet = excelApp.Worksheets('Sheet1');
      }

 function myShutdownExcel()
      {
      excelApp.Quit();
      excelApp=null;
      excelFile=null;
      excelSheet=null;
      }

 function myGetData(column, row)
      {
      return excelSheet.Cells(column, row).Value;
      }

 function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}

 function myOnLoad2()
      {
      var numRows = 33, numCols = 1;
      var tBody = byId('dataTableBody');
      var rowIndex, colIndex, curVal;
      var curRow, curCell, curCellText;
      initExcel(filename);

     for (rowIndex=2; rowIndex<=numRows; rowIndex++)
      {
      curRow = document.createElement('tr');
      for (colIndex=1; colIndex<=numCols; colIndex++)
      {
      curVal = myGetData(rowIndex, colIndex);
      curCell = document.createElement('td');
      curCell.setAttribute('title', 'The value of cell [' + rowIndex + ',' + colIndex +']\nis: ' + curVal);
      curCellText = document.createTextNode(curVal);
      curCell.appendChild(curCellText);
      curRow.appendChild(curCell);
      }
      tBody.appendChild(curRow);
      }
      myShutdownExcel();
      }

    </script>
 </head>
  <body>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div style="background: #009955; width:'100%';" align="center">
        <font color="#000080" size="12pt">
      <b>Get data from excel sheets</b>
        </font>
      </div>
      <center>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div id="div1" style="background: #DFDFFF; width:'100%';" align="center">
      To start the statistics page - Click the button below
      </div>

  <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="GetData(1,1);" />
  <input type="button" value="Next" onClick="myOnLoad2()" />
  </center>
   <b>Get data from excel sheets</b>
  <table id='dataTable'>
  <tbody id='dataTableBody'>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Am I on the right track?  I can only use javascript so don't try pointing me to jQuery or PHP.  Can anyone help or point me to a good resource, I do want to learn this but syntax and me...not such good friends.  Once I see an example I'm pretty good about figuring out how to adapt it but getting it into an array has boggled me for the last week.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, jQuery IS javascript but I understand what you mean. But question: what if the clients browser doesn't support ActiveXObject?

Comment: I've had more success having the user paste in CSV into a textarea and  parsing that into JS arrays.

Comment: The only people who will be using this particular page will have the same browser set up as I do.  It's only a select few who can access it so I know what they have on their systems.

Comment: You can create a global variable using `window.variableNameHere = someValue;` or just set it up as you have for `excelApp` and populate it from `GetData()`. If it needs to be an array then declare as (eg) `var myDataVals=[];` and add repcount using `myDataVals.push(repCount);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of Worksheet names using ActiveX to array in javaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635942/get-list-of-worksheet-names-using-activex-to-array-in-javascript)